# Media print multiple pages table-border-layout

Tags: html, css, html-table, media-queries

When I print this, on the left and on the top of the table on the second page is missing the border. How can I fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @media print
        {
            body { 
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0;
                color: #000000 !important;
                background-color: #ffffff !important;
            }
            * {
                color: inherit !important; 
                background-color: transparent !important;
                background-image: none !important;
            }
            table {
                width: 100%;
                border: 1pt solid #000000;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size: 11pt;
            }
            #space { height: 750px; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <br /><br />
    <h2>.</h2>
    <div id="space"></div>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Amount</th><th>label</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
            <tr><td>20</td><td>pineapple</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your browser ? works on FF6. If you generate a pdf ensure that the zoom is good and it is not a zoom render problem...

Comment: FF6. If I generate a pdf it look a little better but not yet good: there are left and top borders, but they are thinner then the other borders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your table style to have something looks good :

```
table {
    border: 1pt solid #000000;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 11pt;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit :**
To have something looks perfect, first, remove all table border then define each style with what you want, in order to have only one line by border (create border for th, td, tr) :

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 11pt;
    width: 100%;
    border-color: #000000 ;
    border-right: 1px solid;
}

tr {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
}

td {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

th {
    border-color: #000000;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: It looks better, but not yet good. The first page bottom border and the second page top border are only half as thick as the remaining borders.

Comment: If I set explicitly to `none` all borders that are not needed it works.

Comment: So much trouble to get the borders to print nicely, motivates me to design the table without borders. Actually, a border without tables looks nicer. On this SO site I see many tables, but without borders. Of course, this does not directly address OP's question, and is opiniated, but I just want to share my learning curve, as I arrived at this solution with the same problem in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Give margin of the table's border-width to the table to prevent the clipping on second and later pages when your table has a collapsed border.

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; margin:1px;">
    <thead>
       <tr><th>Amount</th><th>label</th></tr>
    </thead>
    ....
```